# Toggle icon when audio played or paused

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem

I have a click handler that is meant to remove the class of `.fa-pause` then add a class of `.fa-play` if the audio is paused (and vice-versa). However, it doesn't do this until the second time I click the play button.

### scripts.js

```
var audio = document.getElementById("painter");

$(".audio__play").click(function(){
        if (audio.paused == true) {
            $(this).removeClass("fa-pause");
            $(this).addClass("fa-play");
            audio.play();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("fa-play");
            $(this).addClass("fa-pause");
            audio.pause();
        }
});
```

Comment: Is your audio pause by default ?

Comment: add a little log output to the beginning of the click function to see if it's even firing, and to see the state.  console.log(audio.paused);

Comment: @Carlos2W Yes, it is paused to start.

Comment: @spozun When I console.log(audio.paused) it's true

Comment: As long as the event is firing properly, you might want to replace remove & add class with .attr( "class", "newClass" ).  It's a little stronger in that it removes all other classes from the element, which could deal with some sort of conflict.

Comment: @spozun Could you show what it would look like in a code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just guessing this. You may be mixing up the icon you want to use with the audio playing state.

For example, when `audio.paused === true` you are playing the audio with `audio.play()`. Shouldn't your button icon change to a pause icon at this point? If yes, then you should be **removing fa-play** and **adding fa-pause** and vice-versa when you pause the audio.

Does this work for you?

```
var audio = document.getElementById("painter");

$(".audio__play").click(function(){
    if (audio.paused == true) {
        // Audio is going to play so we set the
        // pause icon on the button.
        $(this).removeClass("fa-play");
               .addClass("fa-pause");

        audio.play();
    } else {
        // Audio is going to pause so we set the
        // play icon on the button.
        $(this).removeClass("fa-pause");
               .addClass("fa-play");
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it was just a mix-up of which class I was adding and removing in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simplistic working version of what you're trying to do.  http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7234/

I think your problem is that you are selecting something by class `".audio__play"`, then changing the class on it.  That seems a little fishy to me.  I changed the selector to an ID selector `"#audio__play"` in my example.

If you can't get it working, you need to post more code from your page.